# How to get Meteor server to listen on Unix domain socket?

Tags: meteor

My Meteor server needs to run behind an NGINX proxy which receives HTTP requests, adds the Kerberos-authenticated user name to the header and forwards them to another webserver (assumed to be NodeJS) over a Unix domain socket which is accessed through a file secured by Unix permissions.

I would like to use **Meteor** instead of NodeJS, but the only way I can get Meteor to listen on a Unix domain socket is to hack a file called run-proxy.js deep inside my Meteor installation and modify a call to server.listen(...) to pass it a file name instead of a port number.

This works, but is there a better way to achieve this? Ideally without modifying Meteor's code. I did try `meteor --port /home/me/file_name` but it complains that there is no port number.

Comment: You could submit a pull request to the meteor.js contributors and make the world benefit from it!

Comment: QuantumLicht, I have never done something like a pull request, but I am happy to try. However I do need to make an effort to find the best solution, and that is what I am doing.

Comment: even if it does not get accepted, you will probably get feedback about possible ways to solve your issue or a proposal to do things differently.

Comment: You can basically just wrap any Node.js application with fibers/futures and it should work with Meteor.

Comment: @QuantumLicht: ok, maybe I will do that.

Comment: @corvid, I don't have a node.js app,just a Meteor app. It is just that the infrastructure is set up to provide single signon functionality for nodejs. If I want SSO for Meteor, it is upto me to make the best of what is available for NodeJS.